# Joined console output for "Build other projects" in hudson/jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I have created 3 jobs [A, B, C] in Hudson.

Job A has "Build other projects" enabled and it invokes jobs [B, C]. It works fine but I want to see console output for  [B, C] in console for job A. At this moment it looks like this:

```
Started by user anonymous
Triggering a new build of A
Triggering a new build of B
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Can I replace "Triggering a new build of A/B" with job A output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. It can't be done with any of the standard options, and I don't see any plugins that would allow this either (just looked at the list).

Maybe you could write a plugin for it :)